# Pod repo push can not push to git

Tags: cocoapods

I have a private spec repo,such as MXNetworkSpec,when i use this command "pod repo push MXNetworkSpec MXNetwork.podspec",git can not push this MXNetwork.podspec to remote master,it shows that Everything up-to-date. what should i do ?

Comment: Did you try to pull first? _Might_ be due to this.

Comment: This means whatever data you have at the remote master is up to date with your local data.  So there is nothing new to be pushed.

Comment: thanks  @MayeulC,@fmello, i try to rm .cocoapods/repos, and pod setup,then eidit .gitignore_global  rm *.podspec, it will be fixed.